# How to configure API Response cache with HTTP Response status code?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tested APIM performance with API Response cache.
The result was a little different to my expectation.
like below.

The first API reqeust got the 404 response status code from API Service through API Gateway.
So I expected the second response would be 404 response status code from API Response cache.
However it returned 200 response status code (different to the first) with same response body.

I read some note like below from WSO2 document.

> Cache mediator does not cache the response status code of the HTTP response in the cache table. Instead, it returns the "200 OK" status code on a cache hit, which is the default request success status response. If you want to return a different status code when the request gets a cache hit, you can update the response status code in the onCacheHit sequence.

I understood what means the note, but I have no idea how to do that.
It's not my area working with cache mediation, especially mediation syntax.

I want API Response cache to work with HTTP Response status code.
Can somebody guide for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the my own way to solve this problem.
this might be wrong, but it works as I intended.
(API Response cache works, when HTTP Response code is 200, and GET method.)

I edited velopcity_templete.xml file, like below.

```
<inSequence>
    ...
    ## check and set response caching
    #if($responseCacheEnabled)
    #if($resource.getMethodsAsString() == 'GET')
    <cache scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator" timeout="$!responseCacheTimeOut">
        <implementation type="memory" maxSize="500"/>
    </cache>
    #end
    ...
</inSequence>

<outSequence>
    <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
    ## check and set response caching
    #if($responseCacheEnabled)
    #if($resource.getMethodsAsString() == 'GET')
    <filter regex="200" source="$axis2:HTTP_SC">
            <then>
                <cache scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
            </then>
        </filter>
    #end
    #end
    <send/>
</outSequence>
```

If anyone has better and more standard way, It will be very helpful for me.